# OAUTH_TOKEN in Google Cloud Platform REST API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to the Google Cloud Platform REST API.  I have created a service account and its key.

From one of the Google Cloud Platform documentation links I got the REST API provided below.

My question is, how do I get the OAUTH_TOKEN in this example?  I assume I need to do something with my service account to generate this token?  and how long will this token last before it expires?

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer [OAUTH_TOKEN]" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/zones/[ZONE]/instances -d
'{
  "disks":[
    {
      "boot":"true",
      "initializeParams":{
        "sourceImage":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-8-jessie-v20160301"
      }
    }
  ],
  "machineType":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/zones/[ZONE]/machineTypes/n1-standard-1",
  "name":"[INSTANCE_NAME]",
  "networkInterfaces":[
    {
      "accessConfigs":[
        {
          "name":"external-nat",
          "type":"ONE_TO_ONE_NAT"
        }
      ],
      "network":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/global/networks/default"
    }
  ]
}'
```

Comment: The token is good for 3,600 seconds. An easy method to create an Access Token is via the Google Cloud CLI: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token

Comment: @john hanley thank you very much for the information.  so is my understanding correct that in order to run the curl command like this, I must have gcloud auth login to an active gcloud profile, and setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is not what is needed here?

let's say if I am writing a script using the python SDK, and I am able to get most information I need using the SDK, but some other resources I must use REST api to get the information, does this mean I need to use both gcloud profile and set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS?

Comment: What I did is show you a command to quickly get an access token for experimenting. Read the documentation on how to correctly setup the Google Cloud SDK and Tools. `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is for applications that use the Google Cloud Client libraries and not for the CLI. Read this article for details on how to set up the CLI with a service account: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-setting-up-gcloud-with-service-account-credentials/